# How to handle a select with multiple items when only one item is selected

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

I have a select form element and it accepts multiple items.

When the form is submitted I'm adding the items into an array to then handle them then running through the array to perform an action on each item.

I'm coming across a problem when only one item is selected.

The length of the array when one item is passed through is not 1 it's the number of characters in the item that is selected.

```
function processForm(formObject){
  var list = [];
  list = formObject.listElement;

  for (var i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    Logger.log(list[i]);
  }
}
```

The above would log each item if more than one item is selected in the form. If only one is selected the length is the number of character in that one item. How can I resolve this so if only one item is selected we treat this as an array with one item?

Comment: [issue 959](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=959) may be related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through a string as if it were an array would give the behavior you describe. You can convert an array first, if it's not already one

```
var list = formObject.listElement;
if (!Array.isArray(list)) list = [list];
```

Comment: Cheers Bruce! That's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
var list = [];
```

which assigns an empty array to *list*, then:

```
list = formObject.listElement
```

replaces it with whatever is returned by *formObject.listElement*, so the initial assignment is pointless.

You haven't indicated what type of control *listElement* is, it may be a [Class MultipleChoiceItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item) or [Class ListItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item). Both have a [*getChoices*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#getChoices()) method that returns an array of the choices.

If you use that method, there should be no need to test whether the return value is an array or not, it should always be a (possibly empty) array:

```
list = formObject.listElement.getChoices();
```

assuming that *listElement* is one of the above objects.

Comment: The trailing ")" was a typo in the post. Because I'm using Apps Script  the reference to to the list is in the formObject with is passed to the function. I then try to assign the value of the list element to the variable list, which works but if one item is selected it doesn't see it like an array.

Comment: It may be that where one item is selected, `formObject.listElement` is returning the value of the selected item, and where multiple items are selected, it's returning an array of the values. What do you get for `typeof list` for the different scenarios?

Comment: You got it. typeof returned a string if only one item was included. If more than one item was returned it was an object (array).

Comment: Thanks, the documentation isn't the greatest. ;-)